# Firebase onDataChange() method is not entered

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to retrieve text from firebase into rec view, but my code does not work. I have this data in firebase

[image].

I need to get every category and author.

I have this line  `list.add("Milena")` to make sure the problem is with firebase, not the recycler view itself. Recycler view shows only the word "Milena".
And I have line as the first line of OnDataChange method `list.add("M")`. The recycler view doesn't shows the letter.

I already added google-services.json file to my app and added this line to manifest `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`.

Why I can't still retrieve data?

firebase rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth==true",
    ".write": "auth==true"
  }
}
```

code where I'm trying to retrieve list of texts from firebase:

```
    list.add("Milena"); // this word shows in recyclerview
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Category");
    databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
list.add("M");
            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String category = ds.child("Category").getValue(String.class);
                list.add(category);
                for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    author = data.child("author").getValue(String.class);
                    list.add(author);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: did you add `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: I'm adding data to list only once before calling adapter, so  I don't need to update adapter. But even after the method id doesn't work

Comment: I recommend doing some local debugging. Set a breakpoint on the first line inside `onDataChange` and run the code in the debugger. Does it reach that line? If so, step through the code line by line and check the values of all variables. Are they what you expect? Does it go into the loop?

Comment: it doesn't do onDataChange method (I just added list.add("M") as the fisrt line of the onDataChange method. the letter is not in the list. Recycler view just shows what I added before onDataChaneg method

Comment: are you authenticating the user using Firebase Auth?

Comment: No. I 'm  just trying to get  list of texts

Comment: Please don't post [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70941832/how-to-get-text-form-firebase) questions. Please update it instead.